# Customize WooCommerce Shipping taxes with hooks

Tags: php, woocommerce, tax, shipping-method

I'm pretty new on customizing Woocommerce using hook snippets. I'm trying to customize the way to calculate shipping costs and taxes costs of my Woocommerce site: the maths logic is working and so items cost, shipping costs and items taxes are available.

What is not clear for me is:

- which is the **correct hook** I have to use to override the default tax class calculation?
- how can I disable standard tax calculation and **set the WC tax I calculated** ? which function is necessary?
- how can I **display those taxes** into the cart page?

So far I've added into my theme's functions.php file this snippet, that based on each cart product, calculates its new tax cost.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_shipping_packages', 'override_woocommerce_shipping_packages');

function override_woocommerce_shipping_packages($packages) {

    $products_subtotal = Array();
    $products_shiptax = Array();
    
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
        $product = $cart_item['data'];
        $subtotal = WC()->cart->get_product_subtotal( $product, $cart_item['quantity'] );
        $products_subtotal[$cart_item_key] = floatval( preg_replace( '#[^\d.]#', '', $subtotal) )/100;

        $products_shiptax[$cart_item_key] = $product->get_tax_class();

        //based on the product's tax class
        if($products_shiptax[$cart_item_key]=="vat-20"){
            // HERE I HAVE TO OVERRIDE ITS TAX VALUE
        }else{
            // HERE I HAVE TO OVERRIDE ITS TAX VALUE
        }
        
        
    }
    

    return $packages;
}
```

From the WC code reference page, i see many 'set_taxes' or 'set_tax_total' functions. But is difficult to understand on which hook I have to call those functions.

Do you have any explanation and example? Many thanks for you answer!

WC version  5.1.0

Comment: Shipping tax rate is never based on cart items tax rates… Note that Shipping tax rate need to be defined in WooCommerce settings > tax, where you can set "shipping" checkbox option to a specific tax rate (by location).

Comment: Thank you @LoicTheAztec. Assumed that, how can I personalize tax rates using PHP ?

Comment: Better use `woocommerce_package_rates` filter hook… See all [related threads](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=woocommerce_package_rates) using  this hook